# <SELECT> (dropdown) doesn't render correctly when you add a <!DOCTYPE html blah blah blah

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, doctype

I find this amusing and really annoying. On windows XP with IE7/8 the input boxes and dropdown boxes are rendered with a thib border and with rounded corners and they look good.
I was redesigning our intranet (very messy code) and I started putting <!DOCTYPEs and all the "modern" things like css and so on when I noticed the dropdown box is rendered with a "flat square" style that does not match the textboxes... I put up two simple html pages to show all of you what I mean: [test page](http://www.qed.it/go/test/)
Thanks for your help...

PS: same behaviour with Chrome and Firefox...

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior, unfortunately.  A SELECT's height and width need to be adjusted for the size of the border and the padding of it.  So if you want a 100x20 select with a 1px border you will need to set height/width to 100x20 as opposed to most everything else where you would set height/width to 98x18.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the *type* of !DOCTYPE you're using. For a list of doctypes, check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your problem with a simple test-case, however for the samples you provided I can see that the width of the select element is being calculated differently.  This seems to me to be a [Quirks vs Standards mode issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).  In Standards mode the browsers implement the spec more rigorously and thus you'll find issues like this often when you switch between them.  However for consistent cross-browser results you're usually better off using standards mode (by specifying a doctype).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that behavior before as well, and it unbelievably annoying!  THe only way I could find to get around it is to make the select box a few pixels wider than the normal textboxes.  Not an optimal solution, though, so I hope someone else has a better way.  Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML is incorrect:

```
<SELECT style="width:200px"  id=select1 name=select1>
```

When you don't use a Doctype the browser enters in what's called "[Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_Mode)" where it tries to make the best of the given code (usually emulating old browsers). When you add a Doctype it goes into "Standards Mode" expecting standards compliant HTML.

The first problem is that you used an XHTML doctype which demands all tags to be lowercase (`<select>`), the second issue is that you haven't enclosed properties in quotes (`id=select1` instead of `id="select1"`) which is probably triggering the error.

Some browsers even have an "Almost standard mode" (like FF)

(Btw, you're already using css with `style="width: 200px"` :)

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested but nothing changes. The dropdownbox is rendered differently in any case (border style, color, height...)